# How to make, what when check box checked, there would come different options?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, checkbox, jframe

I'm making a java program with netbeans, using jFrame
I want to make program for easy use and for advanced use.
So my purpose would be, whet user check "normal user" checkbox 
he can edit one kind of options
and when he check "advanced user" checkbox 
he would only be able to edit advanced options.

Comment: *"I'm making a java program with netbeans.."*  DYM using the D-n-D GUI designer?  You should avoid using it until you become proficient at using the components and layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create two JPanels, one with the easy use components on it, and another with advanced use components, and then swap them via a CardLayout when the appropriate JRadioButton  has been selected. Note that I would JRadioButtons not JCheckBoxes since your selection sounds to be an either-or situation.

Some useful links:

- [How to use the CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [How to use JRadioButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [The Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

---

As an aside, as per Andrew, I also feel that while GUI builders can help you save time when creating GUI applications it is best to avoid using them til you are somewhat familiar with the use of the Swing library. Otherwise it could shield you from having to know these details thereby allowing you to paint yourself into a corner that can be hard to get out of.

Comment: @user3100454: You're welcome. If later you're still stuck, then you'll want to show code and give more information. Good luck.